# Export DISPLAY with azerty keyboard

Tags: linux, pycharm, rhel7, exceed, azerty-keyboard

How to export a keyboard config with the display in linux (with Exceed client app) please ?

```
export DISPLAY=IP
setxkbmap fr
pycharm
```

The pycharm export in exceed is working but the setxkbmap fr doesnt work. The keyboard in pycharm is in qwerty whereas my keyboard on my server is in azerty (which I need in pycharm). Thanks

I'm using RHEL 7.9. I'm root. Maybe it is exceed side, config wizard ? idk

Answer (score 0):

Answer : Right click on exceed mini windows on task bar then Tools > Xconfig > Input Devices / Keyboard input

However, I didn't find how to activate Alt Gr key